# Office365 Mail REST API: how to ignore ContentBytes in Attachments?

Tags: azure, outlook, office365api

I'm using Outlook Mail REST API to fetch messages, using [get-messages](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/mail-rest-operations#get-messages) API call.

I want to get the attachments together with message result, so I added `$expand=Attachments` to the call and it worked.

I don't need the `ContentBytes` fields in the attachment. So I'd like to find a way to tell MS servers to not send it. This will save bandwidth and CPU.

Is it possible to filter nested properties like Attachment using `$select`? I tried `$select=Attachments.Name,Attachments.Size` but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

We can use the `$select` for the expand item like request below:

```
https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/messages?$expand=attachments($select=name,size)
```